# Transaction Reverted by VM

Tags: reactjs, solidity

I have this function in my smart contract that should be able to transfer an ERC-20 token that I have created from the user's wallet back to the contract in a particular pool (The contract has already sent the tokens to the user previously - there is another function for that)

```
function depositToCompanyReserve(uint256 _amount) public {
        // Check that the requested amount of tokens to deposit is more than 0
        require(_amount > 0, "Cannot deposit nothing");

        // Transfer tokens from the sender to the contract's address
        bool sent = token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        require(sent, "Failed to transfer tokens");

        // Add the deposited amount to the company reserve pool
        poolOfCompanyReserve += _amount;

        // Emit an event or perform any other necessary actions
        emit CompanyReserveDeposited(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
```

I also have a react code that interacts with this function. Its snippet is as follows -

```
async function handleDepositToCompanyReserve() {
        if (depositAmount !== "0") {
            try {
                // Importing WEB3
                const web3 = window.web3;
    
                // Get Account
                const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                    method: "eth_requestAccounts",
                });
                console.log("First accounts", accounts[0]);
                let userAccount = accounts[0];
                console.log(userAccount);
    
                // Get Network ID
                let networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
                console.log("networkId", networkId);
    
                // Load ALCORContract
                let ethSwap = {};
                if (alcorContractAddress) {
                    ethSwap = new web3.eth.Contract(ALCORContract.abi, alcorContractAddress);
                } else {
                    window.alert("Invalid Contract Address");
                }
    
                await ethSwap.methods.depositToCompanyReserve(depositAmount).send({ from: userAccount });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                alert("An error occurred while depositing to the Company Reserve.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Deposit Amount cannot be 0.");
        }
    }
```

The transaction is failing for some reason and I cannot figure out why since the only error that is being thrown is 'Transaction Reverted by VM'

I have tried to debug the code and figure out what the issue is but I cannot find the problem. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.